# How can I print unique data from sql columns?

Tags: sql, select

I have a table with these rows:

id | data

1  | a, c

2  | a, b

3  | c, a

I would like to print every data once: a, b, c

I tried this method:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT data FROM table WHERE id > 0 AND id < 4 GROUP BY data");
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $d= $data['data'];
        $d2 = implode(", ", explode(", ", $d));
        $d3 = explode(", ", $d2);
        foreach ($d3 as &$i)
        {
            print $i.", ";
        }

    }
```

But I get a, b, a, c, c, a,

Comment: Your problem is the table design. You *are* getting distinct data. One is `a, c`, one is `a, b` and one is `c, a`. How shall the DBMS know that you are actually after certain substrings hidden in the stored strings. Change the table design so it contains just one letter per row and you are done with the task.

Answer (score 1):

If you GROUP on the data in your 'data' column you'll group on the entire field, this means that the result is as expected. You either have to change your SQL statement or your PHP code.

I would go for a solution in SQL:

```
SELECT data1 FROM 
(SELECT SUBSTRING(data,1,1) AS data1 FROM table
UNION 
SELECT SUBSTRING(data,3,1) AS data1 FROM table
) AS x
GROUP BY data1
```

(this assumes the function SUBSTRING() is available)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `substring_index()`?  If you have only two values per string:

```
select distinct (case when n.n = 1 then substring_index(data, ',', 1)
                      else substring_index(data, ',', -1)
                 end)
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n;
```

This can easily be extended for multiple values, if desired.